# Emulator with debugging for Sencha Touch 2.2.0 + Phonegap

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch-2, emulation, ripple

I'm looking for a emulator for sencha 2.2.0 + phonegap with possibility to debuging js. I was using ripple eumulator with chrome, but it doesn't work with curent sencha version. Is any alternative emulator with debugging code? (Only for windows).

Answer (score 0):

If you run your PhoneGap Application on the Android Emulator you could use [Weinre](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/) to get a debugger similiar to FireBug or Chrome DevTools.

On the iOS Simulator you can use the Safari WebInspector. It can connect to the browser running on the device and also to a webview inside a App. [This Tutorial](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/workflow-tutorials/quick-tip-using-web-inspector-to-debug-mobile-safari/) explains how to use it.